# Display inline problem

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Consider the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="footer">
                <div id="content">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>AAA</li>
                                <li>AAA</li>
                                <li>AAA</li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>BBB</li>
                                <li>BBB</li>
                                <li>BBB</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Next I apply the following CSS:

```
#content ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#content ul li{
    display: inline;
}
```

The output is: `AAA AAA AAA BBB BBB BBB`
The required output is:

```
AAA BBB 

AAA BBB 

AAA BBB
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just float both lists next to each other.

```
#content ul { list-style:none; }
#content > ul > li { float:left; margin-right:1em; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/geertdd/Cu49F/1/

Answer (score 1):

It appears that **AAA** and **BBB** represent tabular data. Why not use a table?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            AAA
        </td>
        <td>
            BBB
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            AAA
        </td>
        <td>
            BBB
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Tables still have their place in web development. [They are not inherently evil](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/01/tables-anatomy-why-tables-are-not-so.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may try with this instead

```
#content > ul > li {
    display: inline;
}
```

This way only the first `<li>` elements will receive the rule.

**Edit**

You may want to use `float:left` to achieve your result as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JoseFaeti/qyzsg/18/).

Comment: He would have to use `float:left` as your first solution would not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#content ul{float:left; list-style:none;}
#content>ul li{float:left;} /*Only target fist-level li*/
#content li>ul>li{clear:both;}
```

This will display exactly what you try to acheive without using table.

Comment: A bit of an overkill on the floats... you only need one.

Comment: Your right, I saw it when I submitted my answer. I was trying to answer as quickly as possible, wich is not always a good idea. I'll see if I can edit my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by deleting `#content ul li{display: inline;}` and adding the rule below. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/5E7Ac/

```
#content ul li ul{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordering content differently from how it appears in the source is a huge pain in the neck. You are probably better off with a table or a definition list where the AAA and BBB elements alternate. If that is not an option, you could use two fixed-width `ul` blocks floated to the left, with block `li` elements - depends on your design requirements (e. g. how much do the widths vary? should the elements line up vertically?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `#content ul li` to `#content ul ul li`, this should fix the problem.